# One of my iPhone users gets an NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted error

Tags: iphone, certificate

I have an iPhone app in the App Store for the last 3 years or so.

A couple of days ago one of my users complained he is getting an error in the app that I planted there in case when he tried to connect to my servers he gets NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted.

I have checked and double checked my certificates but they all seem OK, I also have thousands of users that use my app every day and don't face the same error.
He tried re-installing the app and switching from WiFi to 3G but that didn't solve his problem.

Anyone has any clue on what might cause this problem for my user and how he can bypass this issue?

Comment: I believe I had this error sometimes when the date on the device was wrong. It's worth taking a look.

Comment: Definitely likely to be the date, or possibly if they're jailbroken then they might have fiddled with the root CAs or something.

Comment: The date is the problem, I get it always in the simulator when I changed my iMac date.

Comment: Thanks guys.
I tried both issues with my user. He says his device is set for Dallas time and the he never cracked his device. I am sure he is not the only Dallas user I've got.
Any other possible reasons for this issue?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271740/a-couple-users-getting-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted

Comment: We're seeing exactly this situation where a single user is getting NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted (aka error -1202) on two different iOS devices. The date settings are normal and the devices are not jailbroken.  Our leading suspect right now is their network is connected to a Disney Circle device.