# Getting kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error when download in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to download a file using `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` in Swift.But when I call the download method its showing the below error frequently.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1202.)" UserInfo=0x7fbac2dd2f60 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/EvFVp1WYxrW15Vy6kfUGIChdHy4HVhatT0p6iQhhG24wzNsQ48CEDs0shjmTbCWb/file?dl=1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/EvFVp1WYxrW15Vy6kfUGIChdHy4HVhatT0p6iQhhG24wzNsQ48CEDs0shjmTbCWb/file?dl=1, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbac2ca07e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1202.)"}

I tried to edit the info.plist but its not working.

Comment: Are you sure you're not on iOS 9?

Comment: My apps deployment target is iOS 8.1.

Comment: If you're using Xcode 7 you'll need to add the ATS below like @loretoparisi showed you.

Comment: @Neethu - deployment target has nothing to do with it, if you are linking with the iOS 9 SDK (Xcode 7) - you need to add the exceptions. Anyway, the reason I asked is because you should see this issue on iOS 9, not 8.

Comment: @iMoses Sorry for my less knowledge.I am using Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add arbitrary loads for `ATS` (Apple Transport Security) like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Please note that this is unsafe, you may want to customize your ATS rules by domain like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>dl.dropboxusercontent.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

[UPDATE]
If we look better at the error we can see the key

**NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey**

Then a tech note by Apple about [HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) may help.
Going though the docs we read

> Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is
>   invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."
>   UserInfo=0x14a730 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.com/,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.com/,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You
>   might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “example.com”
>   which could put your confidential information at risk.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x14a6c0 "The certificate for this server is
>   invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.",
>   NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=}

Well, that's pretty that one, since the error **-1202** in the NSURLErrorDomain domain is **NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted**, due to a possibile issue with TSL.

So we need to check TSL at this point:

We check the certs via CLI:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -host dl.dropboxusercontent.com -port 443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=dl.dropboxusercontent.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=dl.dropboxusercontent.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4569 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 50414926328455F36215516BEB0C40F1DD512C3C0989E0C090DC9277E754B35EFF0CE3AEA4D3FB524FFE071BE2D4426C
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1447281208
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
closed
```

and we can see here that this domain supports **TLSv1/SSLv3,**

We can do this online using SSL Server Test by SSL Quality Labs with the same good results [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=dl.dropboxusercontent.com).

My wonder is if this issue is a duplicate of [A couple users getting NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271740/a-couple-users-getting-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted)
But with the TSL checks above we can clearly see that the domain in question was ok.

So (simple) question

Did your phone time and date were correct?

Comment: I tried with your code, but still gets the same error.

Comment: Do you tried no restrictions (first one) or by domain?

Comment: I used first one also.But still get that error sometimes.

Comment: @Neethu just edited my answer giving you more details, and a supposition.

Comment: Actually I was testing it on simulator and date time is correct in simulator.