# NSURLerrordomain error -1202 Using Appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm working on iPhone application using Appcelerator .Every thing in app working fine .but now one alert shows in this.
[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: Do you use `Ti.Network.HTTPClient` or any APIs or modules that use internet access? Are there any https URLs called that you know might have invalid certificates?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search should bring you to the list of error codes
(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes)

In here, we can find the following

> NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted = -1202

Meaning that there seems to be a problem with the server certificates.

A quick search on this error gives us a possible cause:

The time of the phone might be wrong

([One of my iPhone users gets an NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109945/one-of-my-iphone-users-gets-an-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted-error))

**EDIT**

I have no experience with appcelerator. This workaround is for native only, however, the idea should be the same.

And a workaround, if you were using NSUrlConnection:

Which makes use of

```
NSUrlConnection -connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
```

[HTTPS with NSURLConnection - NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578121/https-with-nsurlconnection-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted)